# how to rotate video in VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

How to rotate video in VideoView for 90 degree ?
Thanks for advices

Answer (score 2):

VideoView does not support rotation of video even if composition matrix is set correctly and rotation attribute is used.

What you can do is to use TextureView and set its attribute rotation="90" (for example). It then will rotate the frames but the aspect ratio is something that you need to handle your self. In order to do so you can use textTureView.setScaleX((screenHeight * 1.0f) / screenWidth)

More details are here: [Rotating an android VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview/16490065#16490065)

Answer (score 1):

may be this

```
android:orientation=" "
```

`vertical` or `horizontal`