# Is it possible to rotate an Android VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview, google-tv

Suppose I want to play a video upside down or sideways on a Google TV. Is there any way to do this on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/googletv-android/browse_thread/thread/5c72f2e6b632e38f), Les Vogel (from Google) writes:

> No

And as far as I can tell this is the only valid answer as of today.

The Media Effects framework mentioned in the other answer does not appear to apply to video.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. What you are looking for is the Media Effects framework:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/package-summary.html

It allows you to apply a variety of effects to images and video.

Comment: Note that this was added in API Level 14 (a.k.a., Android 4.0).

Comment: Is there anything available for honeycomb and above?

Comment: Actually taking a closer look at this it only applies to images. Not sure why the docs say video, but I can't find any way to apply it to a video.

Comment: More importantly, if you read on through the docs it keeps referring to images obtained *from* videos. Guess that's where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

VideoView does not support rotation of video even if composition matrix is set correctly and rotation attribute is used.

What you can do is to use TextureView and set its attribute rotation="90" (for example). It then will rotate the frames but the aspect ratio is something that you need to handle your self. In order to do so you can use textTureView.setScaleX((screenHeight * 1.0f) / screenWidth)

More details are here: [Rotating an android VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview/16490065#16490065)

Comment: Note: TextureViews were added in Android 4.0. Google TV only runs Android 3.2.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks. Fortunately my app requires 4.0 as min version