# Video view rotate 90 degree in android

Tags: android

I want to rotate video in 90 degree.

Current i rotate layout but video can't play.
xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rotation="90" >

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

java

```
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

          final Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(
               Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/UnoPlayList/restaurant_menu_pro_mkv.mkv");

       videoView.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/UnoPlayList/restaurant_menu_pro_mkv.mkv");
       //videoView.setRotation(180);
    //  videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
      videoView.start();
```

Is there any way to rotate video.

example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycall.videorotate&hl=en

Please help me.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview

Answer (score 0):

Use `camera.setDisplayOrientation()` and `recorder.setOrientationHint()` methdos to rotate a video while capturing itself.

```
    camera = Camera.open();
    //Set preview with a 90° ortientation
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    camera.unlock();

    recorder = new recorder();
    recorder.setCamera(camera);
    recorder.setAudioSource(recorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(recorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
    recorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());
    
    //Rotate video by 90 degree
    recorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

Answer (score -4):

Nothing you just set the rotation for the videoview that's all

```
          videoView.setRotation(90f);

          (or)


<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:rotation="90" />
```

Comment: It would display black screen as videoView inherently uses surface view. Because a SurfaceView’s content does not live in the application’s window, it cannot be transformed (moved, scaled, rotated) efficiently.