# How to rotate video view in android?

Tags: android

I want to display video in landscape or portrait mode when user click on custom rotation button. I am using following code.

Video view is rotate but not showing video.

example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycall.videorotate

java code:

```
     videoView.setRotation(90f);
     videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
     videoView.start();
```

I read so many tutorial form google and read stack over flow answers but not getting answers.

Please help.

Comment: I hope this post helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview/16490065#16490065

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working i am using texureview to play video. http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-playing-video

Comment: @Ranjith can you add your comment as an answer