# How to flip(mirror effect) a video in a VideoView?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I know there are ways using TextureViews and some other ways, but can we do a video flip in a VideoView, I tried using the method scaleType of X axis to -1, but just getting a black screen. Is there no way to do a simple video flip for a video being played in a videoview? Am I forced to use a TextureView or other methods?

Comment: I pretty sure you'll have to use a `TextureView`.

Comment: I hope this post helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586526/rotating-an-android-videoview/16490065#16490065

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, the best option is to use `TextureView`... Android's `VideoView` can only play videos straight and not mirrored.

If you want your app to play a video mirrored (for instance if the video was recorded using a front camera), you will need to use a `TextureView`, which can be easily mirrored by specifying `android:scaleX=-1` in the XML file, or `textureView.setScaleX(-1)` in the code. ([source](http://adevelopers-blog.blogspot.be/2014/02/using-androids-textureview-to-display.html))

Comment: thought so, still hoped Google's VideoView was a good enough implementation to do video manipulation, and that I was missing something that might allow it.